# How can I merge two dataframes equivalently to VLookup criteria?

Tags: r, vlookup

I have just recently started using R for my master thesis. I need to match the ID number (uuid) of dataframe 1 to the investee names in dataframe 2.

```
Dataframe 1
investee_name      uuid
1         Wetpaint e1393508
2             Zoho bf4d7b0e
3             Digg 5f2b40b8
4  Omidyar Network f4d5ab44
5         Facebook df662812
6 Trinity Ventures 7ca12f
```

```
Dataframe 2:
investee_name           investor_name     investor_type
1      Facebook               cel            organization
2      Facebook           Grock Partners     organization
3      Facebook            Partners          organization
4   Photobucket            Ventures          organization
5          Geni                Fund          organization
6        Gizmoz              Capital         organization
```

As you can see, in Dataframe 2 the investee names appear mutliple times. With VLookup in Excel I could have easily matched the respective IDs from dataframe 1 but for some reason the merging does not work in R. 
I have tried the following:

```
investments_complete <- merge(v2_investments, ID_organizations, by.x= names(v2_investments)[1], by.y= names(ID_organizations)[1])
```

```
v2_investments_complete <- (merge(ID_organizations,v2_investments, by = "investee_name"))
```

for both options it merges the ID colums but I get 0 observations.

At last, I tried this:

```
v2_investments_merged <- merge(v2_investments, ID_organizations, by.x = "investee_name", by.y = "investee_name", all.x= TRUE)
```

here the merge works and all needed observations are there but al IDs have the value NA.

Is there any kind of merge function that mirrors the Vlookup that I intend to do? I've spent hours trying to solve this but couldn't, so I would be very grateful for support!

Cheers, 
Philipp

Comment: can you check if there are any leading/laggiing spaces in one of the `by` columns.  Try `v2_investments$investee_name <- trimws(v2_investments$investee_name)` and similarly for the other dataset and merge

Comment: Like @akrun I am having trouble reproducing your issue. The last merge command you put in your question seems to work on your provided data. Perhaps you could provide `dput(head(ID_organizations))` and `dput(head(v2_investments))`?

Comment: whitespace was actually the problem. man that's embarrasing haha. Thank you so much for your quick help @akrun

Comment: @IanCampbell also thanks to you for the quick response, I highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there are some leading/lagging spaces in the `by` columns.  One option is `trimws` from `base R` which would remove the whitespace from both ends (if any)

```
v2_investments$investee_name <- trimws(v2_investments$investee_name)
ID_organizations$investee_name <- trimws(ID_organizations$investee_name)
```

Now, the `merge` should work